# Как преобразовать из FieldInfo в тип которым он являлся изначально? Reflection

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть код:

```
private void MapBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fieldName = MapBox.Items[MapBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        FieldInfo[] myFieldInfo;
        Type myType = typeof(GMapProviders);

        myFieldInfo = myType.GetFields();

        FieldInfo current = myFieldInfo.First(x => x.Name == fieldName);


        //gMapControl1.MapProvider = current;

        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode =
            GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
    }
```

Как преобразовать тип, чтобы работала закомментированная строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить значение поля с названием `fieldName` из объекта `current` типа `FieldInfo` необходимо вызвать метод `current.GetValue(arg)`, передав в качестве аргумента `arg` экземпляр класса/структуры `GMapProviders` либо `null` если поле является статическим.

То есть не имея экземпляра типа `GMapProviders` в случае*, если тип нестатический, вы не сможете получить значения любых полей с помощью рефлексии.

*код в вопросе не даёт никакой информации об этом типе